# Pass None into a function that accepts Option

Tags: rust

[rust-ini](https://github.com/zonyitoo/rust-ini) has a function:

```
pub fn section<'a, S>(&'a self, name: Option<S>) -> Option<&'a Properties>
    where S: Into<String>
```

I want to read a file without sections, so I call it like this:

```
let ifo_cfg = match Ini::load_from_file("conf.ini") {
    Result::Ok(cfg) => cfg,
    Result::Err(err) => return Result::Err(err.msg),
};
let section = ifo_cfg.section(None).unwrap();
```

But it gives a compile error:

> unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or
>   generic parameter binding required [E0282]

I can fix it like this:

```
let none: Option<String> = None;
let section = ifo_cfg.section(none).unwrap();
```

How can fix this without the additional line with `none`?

Comment: Note that your `match` block is almost exactly the same thing as just using `try!`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify the type of the `T` in the type `Option<T>` for this `None` with:

```
let section = ifo_cfg.section(None::<String>).unwrap();
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^ forces the type to be Option<String>
```

Alternatively, you could specify the type `S` of the method `section`:

```
let section = ifo_cfg.section::<String>(None).unwrap();
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^ forces S = String
```

You can also look up [E0282's explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0282), although it might not really answer your question at this time :)

---

The syntax `::<T,U,V>` is sometimes called [the turbofish](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse). Some very generic methods like `String::parse()` and `Iterator::collect()` can return almost anything, and type inference does not have enough information to find the actual type. The `::<T,U,V>` allow the human to tell the compiler what generic parameter should be substituted. From `parse()`'s reference:

> Because `parse()` is so general, it can cause problems with type inference. As such, `parse()` is one of the few times you'll see the syntax affectionately known as the 'turbofish': `::<>`. **This helps the inference algorithm understand specifically which type you're trying to parse into.**

Comment: This operator is referred to as [turbo fish](https://twitter.com/steveklabnik/status/659034597062262784) for those who wonder like I did.